# Reorder buffer and not modified registers

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, intel, cpu-architecture

> The reorder buffer can handle no more than three reads per clock cycle
>   from registers that have not been modified recently.

That comes from [Agner Fog's material](http://agner.org/optimize/). But, my doubt is:
Why is important when registers have been modified? Why does that matter?

Comment: The context of your statement isn't clear but I would guess he's referring to the fact that earlier Pentiums increased the number of permanent register reads to three in the hopes that three register read ports would be sufficient for preventing register read stalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, that only applies to pre-Sandybridge Intel P6-family microarchitectures.  (PPro to Nehalem).

This P6-family bottleneck is usually called register-read stalls, or sometimes "ROB-read stalls" because the values get read *into* the ROB during issue/rename; inputs for execution units are always read from the ROB (or bypass network) when dispatching uops to execution ports.

AMD, Intel P4, and Intel Sandybridge-family, use a physical register file design.  SnB-family has no bottlenecks on register read ports.  (Or does it?  Some effect seems to limit throughput when we read very many registers on HSW and (higher limit) SKL.  [My post on Agner blog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=857).  But it might be bottlenecking dispatch instead of issue/rename; I haven't done experiments with bursts, just steady state.  No reason to think the mechanism is the same as on P6-family.)

---

**Recently-modified architectural registers are ones that were written by an instruction that hasn't retired yet**.  The data is already available in the ROB<sup>1</sup>, instead of having to be read from the permanent register file during issue/rename.  There is a limit on how many such "cold" registers can be read per cycle during issue/rename as instructions are added to the ROB.  Nehalem increased it some.

Agner Fog's microarch PDF (which you were already reading) explains the details; see the PPro section, and the update in the Core2/Nehalem section.

Footnote 1: or is in flight being forwarded from one execution unit to the next in the bypass network, for inputs that haven't even finished executing.

Comment: Please recommend me something about microarchitectures  ( possibly short ;) )

Comment: @Gilgamesz: Uh, read Agner Fog's microarchitecture guide, which you already are, aren't you?  Or is that advice from the "optimizing assembly" guide?  Start with the Sandybridge section, since that's the main relevant uarch these days.  Once you understand how the pipeline handles instructions, the advice in the optimizing asm guide will make more sense.